# What is the correct way to read dependency tree?

Tags: elixir

I want to parse app deps tree and generate a map.
I'm currently reading top-level deps like:

```
top_level_deps = Mix.Dep.loaded([]) |> Enum.filter(& &1.top_level)
```

I use **Enum.reduce** in recursive method for **top_level_deps** and then for **dep.deps**.
Everything is good until 4th level where is no deps ...
For example:
App A require B that requires C that requires D - I see empty list when inspect C deps (also no hex packages here).
When I modify app A or B to require D and C not require D then I see all deps in my map.
What is the correct way to read dependency tree?

Steps to reproduce:
1 Create a tmp dir for apps
2 Go to tmp dir and create 4 apps like:

```
mix new a
mix new b
mix new c
mix new d
```

3 Add deps for a, b and c apps like:

```
defp deps do
    [{:b, path: "../b"}] # deps for A app
end
```

4 Add this task to **lib/mix/tasks/** to **A** project:

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Reproduce do
    use Mix.Task
    def run(_) do
        app_atom = Mix.Project.config[:app]
        top_level_deps = Mix.Dep.loaded([]) |> Enum.filter(& &1.top_level)
        result = reproduce top_level_deps, app_atom
        IO.inspect Map.put_new result, app_atom, Atom.to_string(app_atom)
    end

    defp reproduce deps, prefix, result \\ Map.new do
        Enum.reduce deps, result, fn(dep, result) ->
            if dep.scm != Hex.SCM do # filter Hex packages here
                new_prefix = "#{prefix}_#{dep.app}"
                new_result = reproduce dep.deps, new_prefix, result
                if dep.app == :c do
                    IO.puts "No deps here !!!"
                    IO.inspect dep.deps
                end
                Map.put_new new_result, dep.app, new_prefix
            else
                result
            end
        end
    end
end
```

5 Run **mix reproduce**
Current results:

```
%{a: "a", b: "a_b", c: "a_b_c"}
```

Expected results:

```
%{a: "a", b: "a_b", c: "a_b_c", d: "a_b_c_d"}
```

Comment: Not sure why the returned list does not include nested dependencies, but I was trying out a different approach to get your expected result, and have a question: what output do you expected if `b` also depends on `d` (if the dependencies are `a -> b`, `b -> c`, `b -> d`, and `c -> d`).

Comment: @Dogbert: I will catch a collision and do one of operations: first result, last result(override previous) or fallback like: "a_multi_d" - depends of configuration.

Comment: I need to add a disclaimer that Mix.Dep is **not a public API**. You are not supposed to be calling it and there is no guarantee the module nor the function will exist in future Elixir versions. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know why `Mix.Dep.loaded([])` does not contain nested `deps` after a certain level, but since all recursive dependencies *are* present directly in that list, we can build our own lookup Map and use that. Here's an implementation that returns your expected output:

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Deps.Map do
  use Mix.Task

  def run(_) do
    app = Mix.Project.config[:app]
    deps = for %{app: app, deps: deps} <- Mix.Dep.loaded([]), into: %{} do
      {app, deps}
    end |> Map.put(app, Enum.filter(Mix.Dep.loaded([]), &(&1.top_level)))
    recur(deps, app, "") |> Map.put(app, "#{app}") |> IO.inspect
  end

  def recur(deps, app, prefix, result \\ Map.new) do
    Enum.reduce(deps[app], result, fn(dep, result) ->
      if dep.scm != Hex.SCM do
        recur(deps, dep.app, "#{prefix}#{app}_", result)
        |> Map.put_new(dep.app, "#{prefix}#{app}_#{dep.app}")
      else
        result
      end
    end)
  end
end
```

Output with 4 packages, `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`:

```
%{a: "a", b: "a_b", c: "a_b_c", d: "a_b_c_d"}
```

Output with the above plus a new package `e` which `d` depends on:

```
%{a: "a", b: "a_b", c: "a_b_c", d: "a_b_c_d", e: "a_b_c_d_e"}
```

Comment: To fully complete this topic I would like to know why my code does not work as expected. Anyway, thank you for your help. Now it's working really good.